# About C++ vector::push_back() exceptions. Ellipsis catch useful?

Tags: c++, try-catch

I often write code like this :

```
try
{
    vec.push_back(0);
}
catch(const std::bad_alloc &)
{
    ec=1;
}
catch(...)
{
    ec=2;
}
```

Is the ellipsis catch useful? Can you provide some links where I can find everything I need to know about exceptions thrown by cin, vector, ifstream, etc? All C++ things...
Something like *The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7* (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) where you can find functions names, parameters, return values, flags, errno codes, etc.

Comment: You mean something like http://en.cppreference.com/ ?

Comment: It is, if the push_back object is a class object throwing some exception at construction.

Comment: @user2393256 Oh thank you I forgot this one ! But when I look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back I see nothing about std::bad_alloc. Maybe I'm not searching correctly ?

Comment: @ChkLst It's not `push_back()` that throws, it's [`operator new()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new).

Comment: I would say it's generally not useful. If something throws and you don't expect that it should ever throw during normal operation then you want it to fail hard and fail now so that you know something went wrong. `catch(...)` usually serves only to mask exceptions when the proper course of action should be to let the program terminate due to the exception. (The core dump can be analyzed later to determine the problem, if you've enabled core dumps.)

Comment: @0x499602D2 Excuse me... I'm tired...

Comment: You have to see the [allocator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/allocator/allocate/) of vector (by default `std::allocator<T>`) as `std::vector` doesn't throw by itself in `push_back`.

Comment: Don't forget that in an `std::vector<T>`, any of `T`'s members related to insertion into the vector (copy/move-construction in particular) can also throw out of `push_back`.

Answer (score 3):

If an ellipsis catch is really useful is arguable IMHO. You should at least catch a `std::exception` for matching the broader case

```
try {
    vec.push_back(0);
}
catch(const std::bad_alloc &) {
    ec=1;
}
catch(const std::exception &) {
    ec=2;
    // You can inspect what() for a particular reason, or even try to dynamic_cast<>
    // to find out which specific exception was thrown.
}
catch(...) {
    // You have no more type info here, this should be done for last resort (in the
    // outermost scope) only.
    ec=3;
}
```

I left comments about the advantages/disadvantages

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen any restrictions on what exceptions can be thrown but there is footnote 192 which contains this statement:

> ... Library implementations should report errors by throwing exceptions of or derived from the standard exception classes(18.6.2.1 ,18.8, 19.2).

This a footnote on 17.6.5.12 [res.on.exception.handling] paragraph 4 which also contains this sentence:

> ... Any other functions defined in the C++ standard library that do not have an exception-specification may throw implementation defined exceptions unless otherwise specified.

It seems, any decent implementation would throw only exceptions derived [indirectly] from `std::exception`. That is, I would catch `std::exception const&` and probably report the `what()` string povided by this exception in some form (e.g., log it to a suitable destination).